# Apa6 biblatex: only shows et. al at first cite

Tags: biblatex, biber

I got a problem with my .bib file I think. I have to references, where one works perfectly and the other doesn't. First time citing one of these references, I would like to see first name and last name for all of the authors. This only works for my second reference, here is an MWE.

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Wohlin2000,
address = {Norwell, MA, USA},
author = {Wohlin, Claes and Runeson, Per and H\"{o}st, Martin and Ohlsson, Magnus C and Regnell, Bj\"{o}orn and Wessl\'{e}n, Anders},
isbn = {0-7923-8682-5},
publisher = {Kluwer Academic Publishers},
title = {{Experimentation in Software Engineering: An Introduction}},
year = {2000}
}

@book{Rogers2011,
abstract = {.....},
author = {Rogers, Yvonne and Sharp, Helen and Preece, Jenny},
isbn = {0470665769},
publisher = {John Wiley \& Sons, Ltd.},
title = {{Interaction Design: Beyond Human - Computer Interaction}},
volume = {6},
year = {2011}
}

\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[%
 % backend=bibtex   % use BibTeX
 backend=biber    % Use biber
]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document} 
Hello \textcite{Wohlin2000}. How are you? And Hello to you, \textcite{Rogers2011}.
\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

Comment: There is an APA style for `biblatex`: [`biblatex-apa`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-apa) that should do this. Although changing `maxnames` to 999 would display all the names, it will always do so, not only the first time a reference is cited. `biblatex-apa` takes care of that.

Comment: I'm using this in my preamble. The MWE is not from my tex file, but the MWE had the same problem. Is this what you are referring to? 

\usepackage[style=apa, backend=biber]{biblatex}

Comment: OK, I investigated a bit further: Even with `style=apa` (i.e. using `biblatex-apa`) the long name list in `Wohlin2000` is truncated (as it contains more than 5 names). We could modify `biblatex-apa` to always print all names on first cite, if you are interested.

Comment: Yes, I was referring to using `style=apa`. But as I found out just a few seconds ago, that does not help either. (The MWE you came up with shows the same behaviuour but for a totally different reason a document with `style=apa` does.) Do you want `biblatex-apa` to print all names on first cite?

Comment: Yes, but to be more specific, not first name as I turns out, thats not correct for apa6 right? This is for my master, so I want to do it the correct way.
Edit: So all the last names, and then the year the book is written I guess
Edit2: should the first cite, if containing 5 or more names, only show Wohlin et. al? If that is correct, then it's ok

Comment: OK. I'm pretty sure though `biblatex-apa` actually implements the exact APA style guidelines, so probably a maximum of 5 names at the first cite is correct APA style. I will write up an answer anyway.

Comment: That answered my edit2, thanks moewe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`biblatex-apa` prints "et al." even on a first cite if the name list contains more than five authors.

To change that, we can re-define the name custom name format from `apa.cbx`: it just takes one line to be changed (we change `\ifnumcomp{\value{listtotal}}{>}{5}` to `\ifnumcomp{\value{listtotal}}{>}{999}`) even if we have to copy a whole chunk of code:

```
\makeatletter
\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
  \ifthenelse{\value{uniquelist}>1}
    {\numdef\cbx@min{\value{uniquelist}}}
    {\numdef\cbx@min{\value{minnames}}}%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifnumcomp{\value{listcount}}{=}{1}}
              or test {\ifnumcomp{\value{listtotal}}{=}{2}}}
    {\usebibmacro{labelname:doname}{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}{#8}}
    {\ifboolexpr{test {\ifnumcomp{\value{listtotal}}{>}{999}}% standard biblatex-apa has "\ifnumcomp{\value{listtotal}}{>}{5}" here
                 or test {\ifciteseen}}
     {\ifnumcomp{\value{listcount}}{<}{\cbx@min + 1}% normal name
       {\usebibmacro{labelname:doname}{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}{#8}}%
       {}%
      \ifnumcomp{\value{listcount}}{=}{\cbx@min + 1}% first past ul is et al
      % but enforce plurality of et al - only truncate here if there is at
      % least one more element after the current potential truncation point
      % so that "et al" covers at least two elements.
       {\ifnumcomp{\value{listcount}}{<}{\value{listtotal}}
         {\andothersdelim\bibstring{andothers}}
         {\usebibmacro{labelname:doname}{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}{#8}}}%
       {}%
      \ifnumcomp{\value{listcount}}{>}{\cbx@min + 1}% nothing thereafter
       {\relax}%
       {}}%
     {\usebibmacro{labelname:doname}{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}{#8}}}}
\makeatother
```

This makes `biblatex` show all names on a first citation.

MWE

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Wohlin2000,
  address   = {Norwell, MA, USA},
  author    = {Wohlin, Claes and Runeson, Per and H\"{o}st, Martin and Ohlsson, Magnus C and Regnell, Bj\"{o}orn and Wessl\'{e}n, Anders},
  isbn      = {0-7923-8682-5},
  publisher = {Kluwer Academic Publishers},
  title     = {{Experimentation in Software Engineering: {An} Introduction}},
  year      = {2000},
}

@book{Rogers2011,
  author    = {Rogers, Yvonne and Sharp, Helen and Preece, Jenny},
  isbn      = {0470665769},
  publisher = {John Wiley \& Sons, Ltd.},
  title     = {{Interaction Design: Beyond Human - Computer Interaction}},
  volume    = {6},
  year      = {2011},
}

\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage[%
  style=apa,
  backend=biber,
]{biblatex} 
\DeclareLanguageMapping{english}{english-apa}

\makeatletter
\DeclareNameFormat{labelname}{%
  \ifthenelse{\value{uniquelist}>1}
    {\numdef\cbx@min{\value{uniquelist}}}
    {\numdef\cbx@min{\value{minnames}}}%
  \ifboolexpr{test {\ifnumcomp{\value{listcount}}{=}{1}}
              or test {\ifnumcomp{\value{listtotal}}{=}{2}}}
    {\usebibmacro{labelname:doname}{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}{#8}}
    {\ifboolexpr{test {\ifnumcomp{\value{listtotal}}{>}{999}}% standard biblatex-apa has "\ifnumcomp{\value{listtotal}}{>}{5}" here
                 or test {\ifciteseen}}
     {\ifnumcomp{\value{listcount}}{<}{\cbx@min + 1}% normal name
       {\usebibmacro{labelname:doname}{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}{#8}}%
       {}%
      \ifnumcomp{\value{listcount}}{=}{\cbx@min + 1}% first past ul is et al
      % but enforce plurality of et al - only truncate here if there is at
      % least one more element after the current potential truncation point
      % so that "et al" covers at least two elements.
       {\ifnumcomp{\value{listcount}}{<}{\value{listtotal}}
         {\andothersdelim\bibstring{andothers}}
         {\usebibmacro{labelname:doname}{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}{#8}}}%
       {}%
      \ifnumcomp{\value{listcount}}{>}{\cbx@min + 1}% nothing thereafter
       {\relax}%
       {}}%
     {\usebibmacro{labelname:doname}{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}{#7}{#8}}}}
\makeatother

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document} 
Hello \textcite{Wohlin2000}. How are you? And Hello to you, \textcite{Rogers2011}.


Hello \textcite{Wohlin2000}. How are you? And Hello to you, \textcite{Rogers2011}.

\printbibliography 
\end{document}
```

[image]